# How to merge two column in a table based on certain condition in R

Tags: r

I have a table in R like this:

```
      x     Y
1     2     1
2     1     1
3    NA     1
4     2    NA
5     1     2
6     2     2
7     1     1
```

and what I'm hoping to do is make a new column called `xy` which bases on if there is a `1` exist in either `x` or `y`.

For example, if `x` is 1 and `y` is 2 then the `xy` should be `1` ; if `x` is `NA`and `y` is `1` then the `xy`should be `1`. If both `x` and `y` is `2` then `xy`should be `2`.

The priority of the categorical variables `1`, `2` and `NA` is `1`>`2`>`NA`.
In short what my desired output looks like this:

```
      x     Y     XY
1     2     1     1
2     1     1     1
3    NA     1     1
4     2    NA     2
5     NA   NA     NA
6     2     2     2
7     1     1     1
```

I'm new to R and trying to trim my data. Thank you for your help! I'm really appreciated:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
library(dplyr)

df |> rowwise() |>
   mutate(z1 = coalesce(c_across(x) , 0) , z2 = coalesce(c_across(Y) , 0)) |>
   mutate(XY = case_when(any(c_across(z1:z2) == 1) ~ 1 , any(c_across(z1:z2) == 2) ~ 2)) |>
   select(-z1 , -z2) |> ungroup() -> ans
```

- output

```
# A tibble: 7 × 3
      x     Y    XY
  <int> <int> <dbl>
1     2     1     1
2     1     1     1
3    NA     1     1
4     2    NA     2
5    NA    NA    NA
6     2     2     2
7     1     1     1
```

- data

```
df <- structure(list(x = c(2L, 1L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 1L), Y = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, NA, NA, 2L, 1L)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you@Mohamed Desouky! So what if my desired output is a data.frame? what should I do in this case?

Comment: use `ans` as your desired data.frame in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a `case_when` (remembering that it evaluates from the bottom and up):

```r
library(dplyr)

df <-
  df |> 
  mutate(XY = case_when(x == 1 | Y == 1 ~ 1,
                        x == 2 | Y == 2 ~ 2, 
                        TRUE ~ NA_real_))
```

Or apply the same logic using `base` functionalities:

```r
df$XY <- NA
df$XY[df$x == 2 | df$Y == 2] <- 2
df$XY[df$x == 1 | df$Y == 1] <- 1
```

Output:

```r
      x     Y    XY
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     2     1     1
2     1     1     1
3    NA     1     1
4     2    NA     2
5    NA    NA    NA
6     2     2     2
7     1     1     1
```

Data:

```r
library(readr)

df <- read_table("
                  x     Y
                  2     1
                  1     1
                  NA    1
                  2     NA
                  NA    NA
                  2     2
                  1     1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R approach. For each row, check if `any` value is 1 (removing `NA`) and if so, set value of `XY` of 1. Then, check for `any` value of 2 in a similar fashion. If neither of those found, then set as `NA`. If you have more columns, you can subset in the function call for those specific columns to be evaluated (in this case, `x` and `Y`).

```
df$XY <- apply(df,
      1,
      function(x) {
        if (any(x == 1, na.rm = T)) return(1)
        if (any(x == 2, na.rm = T)) return(2)
        return(NA)
      })
```

**Output**

```
   x  Y XY
1  2  1  1
2  1  1  1
3 NA  1  1
4  2 NA  2
5 NA NA NA
6  2  2  2
7  1  1  1
```